# Training a neural network to produce a one-hot encoding vector out of a single feature

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, neural-network, classification, one-hot-encoding

I would like to build a neural network that takes a **natural number** and generates a **one-hot encoding** vector corresponding to that number.

> Example: `2 -> (0, 0, 1, 0, ...)`

More formally, I want it to take an input `i` in `[0, ..., K]` and produce an output vector `(o_0, ..., o_j, ..., o_k)`, where all `o_j` are 0, except `o_i`, which is 1.

However, I am not sure on what the specific architecture should be. I believe it should have more than one layer, since there is no linear relationship between the input and the output.

I have tried several architectures, but the best performance I have been able to get is 33%. I am using the following code:

```py
import pandas as pd
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import random
random.seed(0)
torch.manual_seed(0)

class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(1, 55)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(55, 30)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(30, 25)
        self.relu = nn.ReLU()
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(p=0.2)
        self.softmax = nn.Softmax(dim=0)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.fc1(x)
        x = self.relu(x)
        x = self.dropout(x)
        x = self.fc2(x)
        x = self.relu(x)
        x = self.dropout(x)
        x = self.fc3(x)
        x = self.softmax(x)
        return x
    
net = Net()

# A list of 10000 random numbers between 0 and 24
dataset = pd.DataFrame([random.randint(0, 24) for _ in range(10000)])
dataset['label'] = dataset[0] # The label is the same as the input

train, test = train_test_split(dataset, test_size=0.2)

criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = optim.Adam(net.parameters(), lr=0.001)

for epoch in range(5):
    # Train
    running_loss = 0.0
    for i in range(len(train)):
        inputs = train.iloc[i, 1:].tolist()
        inputs = torch.tensor(inputs, dtype=torch.float)
        labels = train.iloc[i, 0]
        labels = torch.tensor(labels, dtype=torch.long)

        optimizer.zero_grad()
        outputs = net(inputs)
        loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

    # Evaluate
    correct = 0
    total = 0
    with torch.no_grad():
        for i in range(len(test)):
            inputs = test.iloc[i, 1:].tolist()
            inputs = torch.tensor(inputs, dtype=torch.float)
            labels = test.iloc[i, 0]
            labels = torch.tensor(labels, dtype=torch.long)
            outputs = net(inputs)
            predicted = outputs.argmax()
            total += 1
            correct += (predicted == labels)
    
    print('Accuracy of the network on the test set: {:.2f}%'.format(100 * correct / total))
```

I believe my task is pretty simple, but I can't find a good implementation...

Answer (score 1):

You're not disabling dropout before you evaluate, this adds noise into the testing loop which is a problem. You should add `net.eval()` before the `for i in range(len(test)):` line and add `net.train()` before the `for i in range(len(train)):` line to ensure dropout is reenabled during training.

The other major mistake here is the use of softmax inside your model. `CrossEntropyLoss` assumes logits as input (i.e. it assumes that softmax has not yet been applied) so you shouldn't be applying softmax in your model. In general it's a bad idea to apply softmax in the model since it runs into precision issues, but here it's actually semantically incorrect. Note that `argmax` isn't affected by softmax so removing it won't change the accuracy calculation.

Finally, I'm just not a huge fan of dropout anyway since I find normalization-based regularization layers tend to work better (batch-norm, group-norm, etc...). Also, shifting and scaling the input (normalizing it) into a range like [-1, 1] tends to improve performance of NNs (at least this seems to be true when using the default weight initialization in pytorch). I would recommend something more like the following:

```py
class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(1, 55)
        self.gn1 = nn.GroupNorm(5, 55)   # group-norm regularization layer
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(55, 30)
        self.gn2 = nn.GroupNorm(3, 30)   # group-norm regularization layer
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(30, 25)
        self.relu = nn.ReLU()

    def forward(self, x):
        # shift and scale data into more standard range, in this case [-1,1]. Could also be applied before giving data to model
        x = (x - 12) / 12
        x = self.fc1(x)
        # most layers in pytorch assume mini-batch input so reshape x here
        x = self.gn1(x[None, :]).flatten()
        x = self.relu(x)
        x = self.fc2(x)
        # ditto
        x = self.gn2(x[None, :]).flatten()
        x = self.relu(x)
        x = self.fc3(x)
        return x
```

Some other things that could make things faster and better might be

- use mini-batches instead of single values. This may improve accuracy but will certainly make things faster. Pure stochastic gradient descent (SGD) usually doesn't work as well as mini-batch gradient descent. In applied ML the term SGD is often used loosely to refer to mini-batch gradient descent is often referred to as stochastic gradient descent.
- weight decay on the optimizer often improves generalization and convergence rates
- learning rate schedules could improve convergence rates
- shuffle the data in the training dataset between epochs. Better yet write a PyTorch dataset to manage your data and use a `DataLoader` with shuffle enabled.